# how can i configure the embedded Apache Tomcat on the Spring boot maven to execute php scripts?

Tags: java, php, spring-mvc, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a simple maven project. I did exactly as the tutorial stated here but i changed little bit in the Controller class. everything still works except PHP
[Build REST App using Maven](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

The content of **hello.php** is very simple php code. It is located in the src/main/java/webapp/hello.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
HI MY PHP
<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

In **MainController.java** class, here where I call the page using this
it is located in src/main/java

```
package halim.controllers;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
// import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  // @ResponseBody
  public String index() {
    return "hello.php";
  }

}
```

When running the service from the Webbrowser everything is fine, but only this part of my `hello.php` is displayed `"HI MY PHP"` but the other snippet of the php is not executed.

The problem is about how can I configure the embedded Apache Tomcat on the Spring boot maven to execute php scripts?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why you are doing PHP from java application and tomcat?

Comment: I need to control some leds of my Raspberry PI from the web. the library does so is PI4J is implemented in java. I am using Spring maven to do so. every thing works html, javascript . except PHP. I think it is important to have it working in order to process a form for example. in case i would like to add it later.